# Check if conditional with awk for matches in logfile

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk, tail

I want to check the auth.log file for accepted sshd connections and execute an action if any are found.

Here is my code:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log | awk '{ if($0 ~ /sshd/ && $0 ~ /Accepted/) { system("echo FOUND") } }'
```

For some reason, this produces no output. Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to the bufferisation of `tail -f`:

```
~$ tail auth.log | awk '{ if($0 ~ /sshd/ && $0 ~ /Accepted/) { system("echo FOUND") } }'
FOUND
FOUND
```

It works with `tail`, but fails with `tail -f`:

```
~$ tail -f auth.log | awk '{ if($0 ~ /sshd/ && $0 ~ /Accepted/) { system("echo FOUND") } }'
^C
```

A workaround you could use, is using a `while` loop to read each line of `tail -f`:

```
~$ tail -f auth.log | while read line
> do
>     echo $line | awk '{ if($0 ~ /sshd/ && $0 ~ /Accepted/) { system("echo FOUND")} }'
> done
FOUND
FOUND
```

--

Searching `man awk` for `buffer`, I found the `-W` option (but this is a `mawk` version…):

> `-W interactive`
>
>   sets unbuffered writes to stdout and line buffered reads from stdin.  Records from stdin are lines regardless of the value of
>   `RS`
>   .

also:

> `mawk` accepts abbreviations for any of these options,
>   e.g., “`-W i`” and “`-Wi`” …

```
~$ tail -f auth.log | awk  -Wi  '/sshd/ && /Accepted/ {system("echo FOUND")}'
FOUND
FOUND
```

Comment: I solved it via the -Wi option. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use awk's `fflush()` call to flush output:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log | 
    awk '{ if($0 ~ /sshd/ && $0 ~ /Accepted/) { fflush(); system("echo FOUND") } }'
```

That said, your `awk` is needlessly complex. All you need is:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log | awk '/sshd/ && /Accepted/{ fflush(); print "FOUND"}'
```